# Change dynamically file path for log files .NET Core + NLog

Tags: asp.net-core, nlog

In my .NET Core app I use some environments and I want to do different paths to log files for every environment.

For example,

```
Development - c:\logs
Staging - d\apps\logs
```

For every environment I have config section in `appsettings.{env}.json`:

```
"LocalPaths": {
    "LogFileRootDirectory": "c:\\logs\\"
}
```

And part of `nlog.config`:

```xml
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Warn"
      internalLogFile="${logFileRootDirectory}internal-nlog.txt">
    ...
</nlog>
```

What's the best way to implement that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use (NLog) variables.

e.g.

```xml
<targets>
    <target name="file" xsi:type="File"
        fileName="${var:mydir}/logfile.txt" ... >
```

and in C#

```cs
LogManager.Configuration.Variables["mydir"] = "c:\logs";
```

When you change the variable, the path is automatically changed - no reload needed.

See also [the docs for ${var}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Var-Layout-Renderer)

**Update**: you could change the `LogManager.Configuration` after:

```cs
env.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");
```

e.g. your startup.cs could look like this:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
                      ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    //add NLog to ASP.NET Core
    loggerFactory.AddNLog();

    //add NLog.Web
    app.AddNLogWeb();

    //configure nlog.config in your project root. 
    env.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");


    LogManager.Configuration.Variables["mydir"] = "c:\logs";
    ...
```

Comment: Where can I configure `LogManager`? Into `Startup.cs`? Because if I set that into `Startup.cs` `Configure` method I have an error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: after `loggerFactory.AddNLog();`, see https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-(project.json)

Comment: Unfortunatelly no, for some undefined reasons NLog doesn't work for me at all without any errors even without that implementation. But if I try  to insert your implementation I have an error in `Startup.cs`. `LogManager.Configuration` is `null` (`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`). I use `"NLog.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-*" and "NLog.Web.AspNetCore": "4.2.4"`

Comment: I was wrong, it should be after `env.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");`. Have updated my answer. Let me know if it works!

Comment: So, I've updated `"NLog.Web.AspNetCore": "4.3.0", and now it works. Thanks. But custom layout renderers aren't working now.

Comment: auto loading doens't work on asp.net Core yet. Otherwise, create a new question

Answer (score 4):

NLog.Extension.Logging ver. 1.4 supports `${configsetting}` for reading directly from appsetting.json:

```
<targets>
    <target name="file" xsi:type="File"
        fileName="${configsetting:LocalPaths.LogFileRootDirectory}/logfile.txt" ... >
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ConfigSetting-Layout-Renderer

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Environment-specific-NLog-Logging-Configuration

Answer (score 0):

As they state it on their [GitHub repository](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging#known-issues):

> .NET Core issues:
>
> - `${basedir}` isn't working will in .NET Core
> - `LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()` will use the filename instead of
>     the full class name (class name and namespace, like in NLog 4). This
>     will be fixed in the final of NLog 5 (after the release of NETSTANDARD
>     2.0)

So you can't do that right now. Maybe they will fix that in the future.

Comment: FYI, these problems are fixed in NLog 4.5