# Date included in the name of log file using Nlog

Tags: c#, nlog

In my Nlog.config I have mentioned file name as

filename= C:\Support\Comm_${shortdate}.csv

The problem I am facing is that if the tool is executed at 11:30 PM and the execution completes the next day at 12:30 am two files are generated. How can I ensure only one file is generated while keeping the date in the file name?

Comment: Have you tried: `filename="C:\Support\Comm_${shortdate:cached=true}.csv"` ?

Comment: If you are calling logger when you start your execution and when you end it and they are at different date, they will create two files. In order to avoid two files, you need to set the file name programmatically. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42945483/change-dynamically-file-path-for-log-files-net-core-nlog